# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: member.password

Tags: sqlite, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, crud

Its throwing an IntegrityError

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: member.password

How to I fix this?

I was following a tutorial on Flask and the code goes as -

```
from datetime import datetime
current_datetime = datetime.now()

class member(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key = True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, nullable=False) 

    dateCreated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.username} - {self.password}"

@app.route("/UserLogin")

def user():
    users = member(username="1roshanekka@gmail.com", password="qwerty12345" ,dateCreated=current_datetime)
    
    db.session.add(users)    
    db.session.commit()

    print("--Rendering User Login Page")
    return render_template("userLogin.html")
```

Comment: Delete and recreate your database so that it picks up `nullable=False` on the password column - it must not have been there when the table was originally created.